# jquery to hide txtbox

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I want to hide my textbox-X in classic asp according to the date entered textbox-Y.
textbox-X is in different asp page and textbox-Y in different page but both are contained in one base page default.asp i used the following condition and code to hide my textbox-Y, but in vein.

```
if (document.getElementById('txtAmount')) {
            alert("Inside first alert");            
            $("#txtPRAmount1").hide();
            alert("Inside second alert");
        }
```

here first alert fires and but second alert doesnt. please help me

Comment: It is important to know how these pages are seen by the browser. Whether they are in same base page or not at the server side it really does not matter. The snippet you wrote will only work if these text boxes are in 'same' browser window. Is this the case?

Comment: please show us the html snippet too.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes the textboxes are in same browser window.

Comment: onblur='blurCDate(this, txtDteOfBirth, txtAge, sysDate, txtSpuseDOB, txtSpuseAge,optSex);IsPRAllowed(this);' onChange='changeCmnDate(this, txtRenDte);'" On ISPRallowed, im calling JS function and checking the date and making my textbox to hide. Hope this info is enough

Answer (score 0):

If you using ASP.NET and you are using UpdatePanels/Microsoft AJAX you have to call jQuery.noConflict() and later change your code to:
jQuery("#txtPRAmount1").hide();

The code you wrote seems to be correct. So it have something to do with the liberies

Comment: If you just execute $("#txtPRAmount1") in the console, what do you get?
And what do you get if you just execute $
Use Chrome and go to the Console tab.

Comment: i cant work my code in chrome. i dont know why when i try to open in chrome the button click are not working, this is very old code

Comment: Ok, use any other browser and go to the console and execute the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong here..may be some library conflits..anyway give this a try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('#txtAmount').val()!= "" ){ //check if it filled ...assuming its a textbox
            alert("Inside first alert");
              $("#txtPRAmount1").hide();
            alert("Inside second alert")
});
```

Comment: thanks ubercooluk, but the first alert fires, so the if condition should be true.